# Solving recurrence relation when N is very big

Tags: algorithm

How to solve `recurrence` relation when `0 <= N <= 1,000,000,000` ?.

For **example**,

```
like  d[N] = d[N-1] + d[N-2] * 3d[N-3]
```

I try to solve problem using `DP` and `memorization`, but N range is too big to making array. The input N is random.

Is there another algorithm that I can get to the problem?.

Comment: You need to remember only 3 previous values.

Comment: I think you mean [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) rather than [memorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memorization).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to remember 3 previous values. So make an array of size `3` and overwrite each one in to the other for further processing.

```
int[] memo = new int[3];

// some initializations etc

for(....){
    int new_value = memo[2] + memo[1] * 3 * memo[0];
          memo[0] = memo[1];
          memo[1] = memo[2];
          memo[2] = new_value;
}

// further processing
```